# boost::shared_ptr and Inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, shared-ptr

I am facing a situation in which I have a `std::vector` of `boost::shared_ptr`s of a base class. During the course of my program I need to store shared pointers to derived class objects in that vector too and at some time later in the program, need to retrieve those shared pointers.

Following code illustrates my problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base()
    {
    }
};
/******************************************/

typedef boost::shared_ptr< Base > BasePtr;
/******************************************/

class Derived1 : public Base
{
public:
    void derived1_test()
    {
        cout << "derived1_test" << endl;
    }
    /******************************************/
    int i1;
};
/******************************************/

typedef boost::shared_ptr< Derived1 > Derived1Ptr;
/******************************************/

class Derived2 : public Base
{
public:
    void derived2_test()
    {
        cout << "derived2_test" << endl;
    }
    /******************************************/
    int i2;
};
/******************************************/

typedef boost::shared_ptr< Derived2 > Derived2Ptr;
/******************************************/

int main()
{
    Derived1Ptr d1 = boost::make_shared< Derived1 >();
    Derived2Ptr d2 = boost::make_shared< Derived2 >();

    vector< BasePtr > v;
    v.push_back( d1 );
    v.push_back( d2 );
    BOOST_FOREACH(BasePtr bPtr, v)
    {
        try
        {
            Derived1& d11 = dynamic_cast< Derived1& >( *bPtr );
            d11.derived1_test();
        }
        catch (const std::bad_cast& e)
        {
            Derived2& d22 = dynamic_cast< Derived2& >( *bPtr );
            d22.derived2_test();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In the above code, if I change the code in `BOOST_FOREACH` from

```
Derived1& d11 = dynamic_cast< Derived1& >( *bPtr );
```

to

```
Derived1Ptr d11 = dynamic_cast< Derived1Ptr >( bPtr );
```

, I get following compile time error on VS2010

```
invalid target type for dynamic_cast target type must be a pointer or reference to a defined class
```

My problem is that I want to work with `boost::shared_ptr` not references. Secondly, I am using `dynamic_cast` which will throw a `std::bad_cast` exception when object reference is of a different type (tried using it with shared pointers but get the compiler error mentioned previously). That is clearly very slow. I want to be able to use a more performance oriented approach. What I am looking for here is any solution instead of using `dynamic_cast` and exception handling.

Any suggestion with regards to code or change in design are welcome.

Comment: If there is only one derived class or you are certain of it's type, you can just use `static_cast` to downcast.

Comment: Actually this is a much simpler version. In the actual code there are 3 different derived classes.

Comment: And I realized that you are using `shared_ptr` not plain pointers, so disregard my advice.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [dynamic_pointer_cast](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#dynamic_pointer_cast)

Answer (score 7):

Your design seems to be missing the point; it would be better to use `virtual` functions to achive polymorphic behaviour.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

#include <boost/make_shared.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base() {}
    virtual void test() = 0;
};
/******************************************/

typedef boost::shared_ptr< Base > BasePtr;
/******************************************/

class Derived1 : public Base
{
public:
    void test()
    {
        cout << "derived1_test" << endl;
    }
    /******************************************/
    int i1;
};

class Derived2 : public Base
{
public:
    void test()
    {
        cout << "derived2_test" << endl;
    }
    /******************************************/
    int i2;
};

int main()
{
    BasePtr d1 = boost::make_shared< Derived1 >();
    BasePtr d2 = boost::make_shared< Derived2 >();

    vector< BasePtr > v;
    v.push_back( d1 );
    v.push_back( d2 );
    BOOST_FOREACH(BasePtr &bPtr, v) // I use a reference here for efficiency.
    {
        bPtr->test();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If your vectors own the objects, you would be better off using a [`boost::ptr_vector`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_vector.html).

Answer (score 1):

You have several options:

Use inheritance (and polymorphism) properly! i.e. define pure virtual methods in your base class which you implement in your derived class (also, the extra `shared_ptr` type for each derived type is redundant!)

Use a variant type to hold all derived types (useful if you have a limited set). There is no need for dynamic cast then, you can specify a visitor to do what you need to.